# ajax request works in firefox, does not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

```
function ajx(url) {

  var xhri = xhrRequest('xml');
  var ajxOut = '';
  var out = '';

  xhr[xhri].open('GET', url, true);
  xhr[xhri].setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset='+document.characterSet); 
  xhr[xhri].onreadystatechange = function() {

       console.log(xhr[xhri].readyState);

    if (xhr[xhri].readyState == 4 && (xhr[xhri].status == 200 || xhr[xhri].status == 205)) {
      doSomething();
    }
  }
```

An ajax call with this function leads to different result in chrome and firefox: In firefox, doSomething is called, because onreadystatechange is invoked several times and delivers readyState==4 in the end. In chrome, however, onreadystatechange is invoked once and logs readyState==0. How can this be?

Comment: Do you see anything strange in the console or network traces in the chrome dev tools?

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? Is it on the same origin? Does it have HTTP as the scheme?

Comment: that is the solution: ajx("?param1=abc&param2=cde") works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Chrome needs ajx("index.php?param1=abc&param2=cde")